# Link a Acceleo query to a Java generic function

Tags: java, generics, eclipse-plugin, invoke, acceleo

Is it possible to make an Accelo query that invokes a generic Java function?

For instance, let's say I want to create my sort function (not the best example, but it gives the needs)

My Java function will look like this:

```
public static <T extends EObject> T sort(T aParam) {     // Do the sort     }
```

I guess my query will look like this, but I have no idea.

```Accelo
[query public sort(aParam: EObject) : EObject = invoke('com.mypackage','sort(java.util.ArrayList)', Sequence{aList })/]
```